# Reactjs "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.1b232b6f.js:1:1)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess

I came across, in my opinion, an interesting error that manifests itself only in a certain scenario. If you go to the site with a resolution of less than `600px` (that is, after changing the screen width in **DevTools**, be sure to update the site) and open any project and then update the site, then and only in this scenario an error will occur.

The console will get this error: Reactos

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.1b232b6f.js:1:1)".

And if you change and delete, for example, this first line, then the same thing will happen with the next line. He always swears at 1:1. Through npm start everything works fine.

SITE:https://erm-web.ru/projects

Perhaps the problem is in .htaccess, but I can't figure it out. I will be glad for any suggested directions. Where should I dig?

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are describing. I resize the width to be very small, refresh, and it all works fine, no errors in the console.  It only logs out `123` several times

Comment: Not Reproducible. Same behavior as `Chris` mentioned.

Comment: Please put a [mcve] **in** the question (not just a link). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That error looks more like a script that is being lazy-loaded (maybe a chunk of your bundle) and the server replies with some HTML instead of JavaScript code (reason for `Unexpected token '<'`). Are you sure you are not getting a `404 not found` or some `5xx` error?